How to get only country phone code instead of country name and country phone code in Azure AD B2C?
I have B2C application where the country code is showing like:

However, instead of both name of the country and the country phone code. I want to show the "country phone code" [that is only (+1)] only to the user. How can this be achieved? Is there any setting in B2C user journey flow?

In a user flow, No.
You could do this in a custom policy, where you have a Textbox for the phone number, set countryCode to "1" and then create a phone number by concatenating them.

Its not only for the USA. Do I need to do this for all countries ? Please, Any sample code would be helpful.

If you want multiple, use a DropDownSingleSelect for the countries you want. My advice would be just to use the current default dropdown - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#define-a-claim

Sample code here. You need to modify it for just the country code - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/scenarios/phone-number-passwordless/Phone_Email_Base.xml

Is countyCode a typo here? Did you mean countryCode?
